# how to use fprintf in terminal (Mac OS)

Tags: c, macos, printf

I'm using esc ANSI code, ao I need to run my program via terminal. when I'm trying to use `fprintf` and executing the program from the console, nothing is saved in the text file. Running the program from Xcode directly, it does save the text in the file.

```
int main()
{
    int write;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("frucht.txt", "w+");
    gotoxy(4, 10);
    scanf("%d", &write);
    fprintf(file,"%d", write);
    fclose(file);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Please show at the code, at least

Comment: I can't see any reason why this wouldn't write the results to the file. I suspect you're looking for the file in the wrong directory. It will be in your current directory in the terminal, not the directory containing the program.

Comment: Can not reproduce the problem. Try to verify where you look for your file and maybe assure that the file could be created: if(file==NULL) exit(1);

Comment: Did you type in a number and press enter?

Comment: You don't show any error checking on any of the functions.  Both `fopen()` and `scanf()` should be checked.  The `fprintf()` would perhaps be better with a newline at the end, but that isn't strictly necessary.  The `gotoxy()`  suggests you're using the curses (or ncurses) library; in that case, you should probably not be using `scanf()` but a curses-based analogue to `scanf()`.  The code should print whatever value is in `write()` even so, assuming you run the program in a directory where you can write.  However, the program would probably crash if you couldn't create/write files.

Comment: Given that you're getting errors, you should check `fprintf()` and probably even `fclose()`, though many times people don't check them and get away with it.

Comment: regarding: `file = fopen("frucht.txt", "w+");`  This will (possibily) create the file, and if the file already exists, it will truncate the file.  Is that what you want?

Comment: You state that your using the ANSI escape sequences, (probably in the function: `gotoxy()` but you did not post that function, nor the `main()` function.  Please post a [mcve] that shows the problem, so we can help you.

Comment: the main problem I'm seeing in the posted code is the statement: `file = fopen("frucht.txt", "w+");` as, each time this is executed, the file: `frucht.txt` will be truncated.  So, at best it will only contain the results of the execution of the `new()` function

Comment: There's no `gotoxy` function in C. Where did you get it? Please show your **entire** program, that's including all `#include` directives.